# Certain link not opening in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, hyperlink

I've created a new html page and all other links are opening fine except the one directing to this page. Clicking the link in Internet Explorer simply does nothing, but if I open the file directly it opens it. No problems in Chrome whatsover.

What's happening here?

```
<a class="m04" href="cariere.html"><strong>CARIERE</strong></a>
```

Thanks

**EDIT** I think the issue is with the page itself, what could make IE refuse to open a page?

**EDIT2** OK, here's `cariere.html`:

```
`Content removed`
```

**EDIT3** Problem solved, I did a rollback while saving the changes I made and now everything is navigating correctly. Still, very strange even for IE.

Comment: pls provide some markup of what you are referring to.

Comment: I did, but there's nothing unusual.

Comment: Open the console and check the Network tab when you click it.

Comment: No traffic for the link at all.

Comment: There's likely some Javascript preventing it from running when clicked. Edit the element in the Inspector, remove the `href` and re-type it to make sure it's not harboring any curly quotes or whatnot, too.

Comment: The page with the anchor element has no scripts whatsoever.

Comment: And like I said it works fine in Chrome or opening it directky in IE.

Comment: What's on the page you're going to? If all other links on the page are working fine in IE for you, then I feel it's something on the new page itself that's causing the issue and simply isn't compatible with IE, considering it works fine when you use Chrome. When you click on the link, does it "spin" as if it's loading but never loads? No indicators? Have you already cleared the cache in IE? Default security? Cookies? If you can, post up the markup for the page you're linking to. That'll help us determine if it's compatibility issue with that page. Post the markup surrounding that anchor also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting errors, IE is opening other links, and it works fine in Chrome... First glance, this sounds like an issue with the way that IE cached your website. However, I can't elaborate on further possibilities because you didn't provide us with much information or any code to investigate, so basic troubleshooting is the best answer as of right now. I'll update it again if you provide more information.

Try this:

- Tools(gear/cog)->Internet Options
- Browsing history (general tab)->Delete
- You'll want to check the Temporary Internet Files and website files, 
  Cookies and website data. Uncheck "Preserve Favorites website data." 
  Then click 'Delete' at the bottom.
- Click the 'Security' tab and at the bottom click 'Default level'
- Click the 'Privacy' tab and click 'Default'
- Test it. If the above doesn't work, you can always click the 'Advanced' tab and click the 'Reset' button. I've seen IE do stranger things, so hopefully it's as simple as this.

As mentioned, you didn't provide us with much to work with. We're all happy to help you out, so if this doesn't work for you, please come back and post us more information/code so we can get this pinpointed. There are many things, code wise, that can cause undesired results, but we can't confirm that without seeing the code.

---

This has helped me out with various strange "IE bugs." I can't provide you with an explanation, but I'm sure a search could shine further light on this. It's at least worth trying considering how strange this bug is.

In your `<head>` put:
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>`

Comment: I did this, twice. Stranger than that, two very similar html files that contain this same hyperlink behave differently; one redirects to the pge correctly, the other doesn't. I even checked with a diff checker tool and didn't see anything relevant.

Comment: You using any type of jQuery/JS on your pages?

Comment: On some of them, including the page 'cariere.html' I use jQuery yes, but like I said  I get no script errors and IE opens the page fine if I open it directly from the context menu. And like I said, one of the pages, the only one, redirects without issues when I click on the link. It's very very weird indeed.

Comment: Agreed, this is very weird. lol I've only been web developing over about a year now (versus desktop application), and IE seems like it's always there to be a real pain in my ass with everything. Are you hosting this local or is it possible for me to take a look at it? I'm about to update my answer with something that has helped me with various IE bugs over this past year. I can't explain what it is or what it does, I just know it's helped me with similar strange issues with IE.

Comment: I've added the source to `cariere.html`.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything with your source that screams out as being a problem, especially this type of problem. Try adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>` to your `<head>` and let me know if that helps any. As mentioned, I haven't researched extensively into that, but I know it's resolved MANY random, strange IE bugs for me. It's worth a shot, if nothing more. I'd add it on the page with the link as well.

Comment: I added that after my 'meta' tags. Nothing changed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the issue was resolved by downloading an older copy of the site's content.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the problem before, and it's a very weird one: it works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but it's not stable in IE. Sometimes it works, but in most time it just won't work.

The problem is that a *label* tag is imbedded in the *a* tag, the link works only in the padding area between *label* tag and *a* tag. It can be easily fixed by change the *lable* tag into *span* tag.

From:

```html
<a href="www.google.com"><label>Learn More</label></a>
```

To:

```html
<a href="www.google.com"><span>Learn More</span></a>
```